# Count number of nans between two numbers in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a Pandas DataFrame with consumption measurements over several days, so that a measurement on a given day represents the consumption over all the previous days without measurements. For each consumer (a row), I have something like

```
Nan, 10, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, 21, Nan, ...
```

meaning that the average consumption between the `10` and the `20` was `21/7=3`, i.e., 21 divided by (six NaNs plus one).

The measurements come at irregular intervals, so I need to divide each measurement by the number of NaNs between it and the previous measurement. I want my output from the example above to be `Nan, 0.4347, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, 3, Nan, ...`. The first measurement should be divided by 23, but I can live without getting it right. How can I do this? Here is an example of my data:

```
SP ID,2016-12-28,2016-12-29,2016-12-30,2016-12-31,2017-01-01,2017-01-03,2017-01-04,2017-01-05,2017-01-06,2017-01-09,2017-01-10,2017-01-11,2017-01-12,2017-01-13,2017-01-16,2017-01-17,2017-01-18,2017-01-19,2017-01-20,2017-01-21,2017-01-23,2017-01-24,2017-01-25,2017-01-26,2017-01-27,2017-01-29,2017-01-30,2017-01-31,2017-02-01,2017-02-02,2017-02-03,2017-02-06,2017-02-07,2017-02-08,2017-02-09,2017-02-10,2017-02-13,2017-02-14,2017-02-15,2017-02-16,2017-02-17,2017-02-18,2017-02-21,2017-02-22,2017-02-23,2017-02-24,2017-02-27,2017-02-28,2017-03-01,2017-03-02
100854,,,4.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,3.0,,
120355,,,9.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9.0
200357,,,,,,,,,,,18.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,22.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

The expected output is below (dividing the first occurrence by 23). We have for example `4.0/25=0.16`.

```
SP ID,2016-12-28,2016-12-29,2016-12-30,2016-12-31,2017-01-01,2017-01-03,2017-01-04,2017-01-05,2017-01-06,2017-01-09,2017-01-10,2017-01-11,2017-01-12,2017-01-13,2017-01-16,2017-01-17,2017-01-18,2017-01-19,2017-01-20,2017-01-21,2017-01-23,2017-01-24,2017-01-25,2017-01-26,2017-01-27,2017-01-29,2017-01-30,2017-01-31,2017-02-01,2017-02-02,2017-02-03,2017-02-06,2017-02-07,2017-02-08,2017-02-09,2017-02-10,2017-02-13,2017-02-14,2017-02-15,2017-02-16,2017-02-17,2017-02-18,2017-02-21,2017-02-22,2017-02-23,2017-02-24,2017-02-27,2017-02-28,2017-03-01,2017-03-02
100854,,,0.17,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.16,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.15,,
120355,,,0.391,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.375,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.391
200357,,,,,,,,,,,0.78,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.917,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a custom function on each row using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1`. Inside the function, you can find the non-null indices and the difference between each consecutive pair. For the first diff, we can hard-code it to 23 as desired.

```
def row_norm(row):
    indices = row.reset_index(drop=True)
    indices = indices[indices.notna()].index.values
    diffs = [e-s for s, e in zip(indices, indices[1:])]
    
    diffs[0] = 23
    row.iloc[indices[1:]] = row.iloc[indices[1:]].astype(float) / diffs
    return row

df.apply(row_norm, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
SP ID  2016-12-28  2016-12-29  2016-12-30  2016-12-31  2017-01-01  2017-01-03  2017-01-04  2017-01-05  2017-01-06  2017-01-09  2017-01-10  2017-01-11  2017-01-12  2017-01-13  2017-01-16  2017-01-17  2017-01-18  2017-01-19  2017-01-20  2017-01-21  2017-01-23  2017-01-24  2017-01-25  2017-01-26  2017-01-27  2017-01-29  2017-01-30  2017-01-31  2017-02-01  2017-02-02  2017-02-03  2017-02-06  2017-02-07  2017-02-08  2017-02-09  2017-02-10  2017-02-13  2017-02-14  2017-02-15  2017-02-16  2017-02-17  2017-02-18  2017-02-21  2017-02-22  2017-02-23  2017-02-24  2017-02-27  2017-02-28  2017-03-01  2017-03-02
0  100854.0         NaN         NaN    0.173913         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        0.16         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        0.15         NaN         NaN
1  120355.0         NaN         NaN    0.391304         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN       0.375         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN    0.391304
2  200357.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN    0.782609         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN    0.916667         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```